# How can the value of a variable on a certain line of code become false?

Tags: php, boolean, php-7, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

```
<?php
    include( 'baza.php' ); 
    session_start(); 

    if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

    $sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = :login AND pass = :pass'); 
    $sth->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $sth->bindParam(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR); 

    $sth->execute(); 

    $result = $sth->fetch(); 

    if($result && isset($result['id'])) {
        $_SESSION['logged'] = true; 
        $_SESSION['userLogin'] = $result['login'];
    header('location:index.php'); 
    }
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || $_SESSION['logged] == false) {
?>
    <form action="session.php" method="post">
    Login: <br>
    <input type="text" name="login"><br><br>
    Pass: <br>
    <input type="password" name="pass"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj">
    </form>
<?php
    die; 
}
?>
```

This is a file that checks if a user is logged and if not the code thisplays a person a login form. The code includes a database connection code on line 2 (writing just in case you want to know).

I don’t understand the line 55 and strictly the “$_SESSION[‘logged’] == false” part on that line. I mean on the like 19 we set the $_SESSION[‘logged’] to true if two of the listed considtions are met but how is it possible that the $_SESSION[‘logged’] can turn into “false” state (or value), by looking at or by following this code (since line 18 to line 25). As far as I was checking it with a testing PHP code it can be NULL (like not set or something like that) but if id does not get set to true there is no way of this becoming “false” on its own, by looking how this code works. I basically don’t understand how $_SESSION[‘logged’] can become “false” (in the value that it has / carries) by looking at this code. It can be either “true” (set by the line 19) or not set (I guess), which could be this NULL value (I think that I have gotten that when I was testing).

Something like this and sorry about bothering, but I am stuck. I am trying to grasp it before moving on (how it can be “false”, why is he checking for that in his code)?

Comment: maybe the session value gets set like that somewhere else, e.g. in a logout script or something?

Comment: @ADyson - there is no log out script, this is the only thing that he is talking about, meaning all the known context is this listed piece of code.

Comment: Surely if you have a login code, you must somewhere else, probably in another script in the same application, have some code for logging out. Otherwise how can the user ever log out from the application? Are you really certain that nothing like that exists in the codebase? Don't forget Session variables are shared across scripts.

Comment: @ADyson - Thanks for looking at the question. This is from a YouTube series and he creates this in one video after another, something like this. I have gotten to this point and there is no talking about something like a logout script. He talks about this piece of code, explains it and there is nothing else related to this. And with this said, I basically dont get that "$_SESSION['logged'] == false" part - he explains this "we are checking if there is any value set in this variable" (after first checking if it exists). I am basically looking at it and I am stuck, I dont get this part.

Comment: Maybe he creates the logout code later in the video, or in another part of the series? Just a guess. But you're correct there's no way the code above could ever make `$_SESSION['logged']` be equal to `false`. So either it's a mistake (which you can then safely remove), or the original writer intended this code to work with another piece of code for logging out.

Comment: P.S. Whoever wrote this, if they're making tutorials online, should know better than to use md5 for hashing passwords. [This algorithm has been obsolete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) for several years, as it can now be cracked easily by modern hardware. Please use PHP's ready-made, modern and supported [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) functions instead.

Comment: @ADyson - If you dont set the $_SESSION['logged] to true it gets set to NULL and if you run it as $_SESSION['logged] == false - it wil be a positive condition (like if you use an if statement and echo something if this condition is met it will echo it). On the other hand if you do $_SESSION['logged'] === false (notice the three equals to signs instead of just two like in the example before) it would not echo anything. So something like this - NULL and this is YES with "==" and NO with "===".

Comment: But as far as this example goes I still dont understand why is he checking for this condition in the code, the second one the "|| $_SESSION['logged] == false". Like you said maybe he creates some piece of coding for logging out at a later point in time. To me, just checking for the first condition would be enough - "!isset($_SESSION['logged'])" - so I am assuming, what you have suggested, if there is no other code (like for the log out functionality) I can delete the second part.

Comment: "If you dont set the $_SESSION['logged] to true it gets set to NULL and if you run it as $_SESSION['logged] == false - it wil be a positive condition"...yes that's correct (because of PHP's loose typing, and concepts of truth-iness and false-iness) but it's redundant to check for that because of the `isset` test before it anyway.

Comment: So yes, unless there is specific code elsewhere to set the value explicitly to `false`, then you can remove this test.